# Adding endless scrolling to users index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I added endless scrolling to the messaging system for the inbox and sent folders. However I am not able to apply the same code to the Users controller and index view. Can someone assist? I included the working code from my inbox messaging system. Not sure where I was going wrong in implementing it for Users.

Users controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @users = @user.present? ? User.where('id != ?',@user.id) : User.all
    render layout: 'new_application'    
  end
```

/users/index.html.slim:

```
  #btm_container
    .wrapper
      .box_detail
        = render collection: @users, partial: 'users/user', as: :user
```

Conversations controller:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    inbox_page = params[:page] if params[:inbox].present?
    mailbox = @user.mailbox
    @inbox = mailbox.inbox.paginate(:page => inbox_page, :per_page => 5)
    render layout: 'new_application'
  end
```

conversations/index.html.slim:

```
.wrapper
        = render collection: @inbox, partial: 'conversations/conversation', as: :conversation
        .hide#inbox_pagination
          = will_paginate @inbox

javascript:
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#send_trash").click(function(){
        var ids = [];
        $('input.conversation_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            ids.push($(this).data('id'));
        });

        $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url:"/conversations/trash_all",  data:{ids: ids}});
    });


    $('#inbox .pagination a').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href')
      if (href != 'undefined' && href != null) {
        var link = href.split('?')
        href = link[0]+'.js?'+link[1]
        $(this).attr('href',href+'&inbox=true')
      }
    })

    if ($('#inbox .pagination a').length > 0) {
      $('#inbox').infinitescroll({
        loading: {
          msg: null,
          msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of messages...</em>",
          speed: 'fast',
        },
        finishedMsg: '<em> No More Messages </em>',
        navSelector: 'div#inbox_pagination',
        nextSelector: 'div#inbox_pagination a.next_page',
        itemSelector: 'div#inbox div.outer',
        debug: true,
        appendCallback: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        errorCallback: function(data){console.log('data', data);},
        prefill: false
      },
      function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').jqTransCheckBox();
       }
       );
    }

  })
```

Comment: From the code you've included - the controllers look quite different. Also - can you please strip out any irrelevant code and keep just the code that's relevant to this question (so we don't have to wade through it all)? Finally "it went wrong" isn't a very specific description of what you actually see in your users page... or what you are expecting to see instead. Perhaps you could be more precise? thanks. :)

Comment: @TarynEast I will edit the code. I tried to make the conversion, the problem was taking place in the Users controller. I as working off the lines ```inbox_page = params[:page] if params[:inbox].present?``` and ```@inbox = mailbox.inbox.paginate(:page => inbox_page, :per_page => 5)``` since those are responsible for the endless pagination (minus the javascript). Since the inbox setup is completely different from Users, it's getting me confused with how to apply the same pagination to users.

Comment: Surely you'll still have a `params[:page]` so: `@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>5)` ?